# How to override my accounts address form?

Tags: magento-2.1, overrides

I tried,

**Test/Myaccount/etc/module.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
   <module name="Test_Myaccount" setup_version="1.0.0">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
    </sequence>
   </module>
 </config>
```

**Test/Myaccount/view/frontend/templates/address/edit.phtml**

```
<form class="form-address-edit" action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getSaveUrl() ?>" method="post" id="form-validate" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('* Required Fields') ?>">
<fieldset class="fieldset">
    <legend class="legend"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Contact Information') ?></span></legend><br>
    <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
    <input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getSuccessUrl() ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getErrorUrl() ?>">
    <?php echo $block->getNameBlockHtml() ?>
    <div class="field company">
        <label class="label" for="company"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Company12313123') ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="text" name="company" id="company" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Company') ?>" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getAddress()->getCompany()) ?>" class="input-text <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('company') ?>">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Test\Myaccount\view\frontend\layout\customer_account_edit.xml**

```
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<update handle="customer_account"/>
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="content" template="Test_Myaccount::address/edit.phtml"></referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

It does not work.

Answer (score 1):

**For Community Edition :**

> Test\Myaccount\view\frontend\layout\customer_address_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_address_edit">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Test_Myaccount::address/edit.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

I hope, this will help you. Cheers !!!